# Unused import statement "import lxml" in Pycharm

Tags: python-3.x, pycharm, initialization

My code:

```
import requests
import bs4
import lxml

res = requests.get("https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pacific_blue-eye")
page = res.text
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(page, "lxml")
```

How would I initialize lxml? Im new to python and web scraping so please forgive me if I did something stupid. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No need for lxml just use html.parser instead, Here's an example:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
req = requests.get("https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pacific_blue-eye")
soup = BeautifulSoup(req.content, 'html.parser')
objs = soup.find_all('a', href=True)
for obj in objs:
    print(obj['href'])
```

anyway you should have bs4 and requests modules installed.
for more information you need to read the documentation [beautifulsoup documentation](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/), Hope I help a little